# Combine many arrays to make one modified array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, google-visualization

I have four arrays that I want to use combine and modify.  I want to use them in google visualization columnChart.  Here is hwo they are at first.

```
var arrayOne = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var arrayTwo = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
var arrayThree = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
var arrayFour = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'];
```

I want convert them to list as such.  With the text from arrayFour at first position of the new arra with the relative index from each array  to make a multidimensional array with six arrays;  The numerical order of the numbers in each array have no meaning but representing an integer.

```
var allArray = [['one', 1, 2, 3],
['two', 2, 3, 4],
['three', 3, 4, 5],
['four', 4, 5, 6],
['five', 5, 6, 7],
['six', 6, 7, 8]];
```

Comment: And what have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

There probably is some faster approach, but this is the most straightforward:

```
var arrayOne = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var arrayTwo = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
var arrayThree = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
var arrayFour = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'];
var arrayLength = arrayOne.length;

var arrayOutput = [];

for(var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
{
    arrayOutput.push([
        arrayFour[i],
        arrayOne[i],
        arrayTwo[i],
        arrayThree[i]
    ]);
}

console.log(arrayOutput);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrays = [arrayFour, arrayOne, arrayTwo, arrayThree];
var maxLen = Math.max.apply(null, arrays.map(function(currentItem) {
    return currentItem.length;
}));
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < maxLen; i += 1) {
    var tempArray = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < arrays.length; j += 1) {
        tempArray.push(arrays[j][i]);
    }
    result.push(tempArray);
}
console.log(result);
```

**Output**

```
[ [ 'one', 1, 2, 3 ],
  [ 'two', 2, 3, 4 ],
  [ 'three', 3, 4, 5 ],
  [ 'four', 4, 5, 6 ],
  [ 'five', 5, 6, 7 ],
  [ 'six', 6, 7, 8 ] ]
```